# How do I convert DateTime String to DateTime Hours Minutes Seconds?

Tags: c#, datetime-format

I have this code:

```
stringBuilder2.Append(this.L("PrintEmail_InvoiceDate") + " " + 
    (invoice.Date.HasValue 
         ? DateTime.Parse(invoice.Date.ToString()).ToShortDateString() 
         : ""));
```

which outputs my invoice date like this: 6/19/2017

I need the same code to output invoice date like this: 6/19/2017 12:00:00 AM

How do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried removing ToShortDateString()?

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: If you have a question about how something works, and that something is built into the framework, check the documentation first!

Comment: @kblok comment is the best place to go but I feel I should ask: is the Date property of invoice already a DateTime object?

Comment: It seems simple enough, but simply removing ToShortDateString() throws a syntax error and I am completely new to the syntax, so it gives me an error of identifier expected. I need to know why and please show the correct fix. Thanks again.

Comment: I think he (and myself included) was referring to the fact that invoice.Date looks like it may already be a datetime object because it has ToString() on it, in which case replacing the whole thing with invoice.Date.ToString("g") would work

Comment: Sidenote: why you store the `Invoice.Date` in a string property at all?

Comment: Thank you Tien Nguyen and Steve, both of these examples work and greatly appreciated. I am such a newb to the syntax and was handed this code to fix. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 stringBuilder2.Append(this.L("PrintEmail_InvoiceDate") + " " + 
        (invoice.Date.HasValue 
             ? DateTime.Parse(invoice.Date.ToString()).ToString("G") 
             : ""));
```

The format specifier "G" in ToString() will output mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss (am/pm)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use `.ToShortDateString()`?

Remove it, you will see it works.

Working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gKWAzl

Answer (score 0):

```
stringBuilder2.Append(this.L("PrintEmail_InvoiceDate") + " " + 
        (invoice.Date.HasValue 
             ? invoice.Date.Value.ToString("M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
             : ""));
```

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: I think using "g" as the format specifier would be better, because that coupled with culture info works better.

Comment: using "g" is 6/15/2017 12:00 AM result. Millisecond is not shown.

Comment: According to his question he did not: "I need the same code to output invoice date like this: 6/19/2017 12:00:00 AM"

Comment: month = 6, day = 19, year = 2017, hour = 12, minute = 00, second = 00, tt = AM. But if use "g" second is not show.

Comment: I agreed with you on that, and said use a G, that is a capital G which does output seconds, it is different than a lower case g

Comment: From msdn:Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("G", 
                  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us")));
// Displays 4/10/2008 6:30:00 AM

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147091/discussion-between-tien-nguyen-and-steve).

Comment: Actually using Steve's code is exactly what I was after. Showing seconds, but not milliseconds. Thanks again. I selected Steve's as the best answer. Thanks again Tien for the other answer and input.